kinit: device or resource busy while getting initial credentials
I'm trying to cifs mount a drive. I've installed the necessary tools. Now the kinit myusername@MYHOST.COM fails with
kinit: device or resource busy while getting initial credentials
I looked around and found the question nowhere.
Finally this idiotic kludge worked
touch /tmp/krb5cc_MYUID
